# Unexpected value when counting the number of words in a textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.cal = function (){
    var totalItems = stringSplit($scope.eatables);
    $scope.value = totalItems;
    if(totalItems == 0){
        $scope.message = "Please enter something";
    }else if(totalItems <= 3){
        $scope.message = "Enjoy!";
    }else{
        $scope.message = "TOO MUCH!";
    }
};

function stringSplit(string){
    var array = string.split(" ");
    var x = array.length;
    return x;
};
```

I'm calling this function on `ng-click`, but when the input box is empty it is still giving a value of 1. Why is that?

Comment: `split` will always return an array with at least one element within.

Comment: then how to fix this

Comment: before splliting check string has vavlue or not if it has value then only split other wise x =0

Comment: Thanks vicky your solution works.

Comment: @RajeevMalik The right way to thank someone on StackOverflow is by accepting their answer

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
function stringSplit(string){
    var array = string.split(" ");

    var x = array.length;

    return (array[i] === "" || array[i] === null || array[i] === undefined) ? 0 : x;  //Check whether first element is empty
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because
model value comes as ""(empty string) it is not undefined not if you try to split it it will be array of length 1 whose first value is ""
string
""
string.split(' ')
[""]

so to fix this before splitting it you can check whether some value is there or not then only split

change your function like this

```
function stringSplit(string){
var x
if(string){
var array = string.split(" ");
 x = array.length;
alert(string)
alert(x)
return x;
}else {

x =0
return x

}
};
```

here is working code pen sample
http://codepen.io/vkvicky-vasudev/pen/XjkZBN